# Jupyter lab, drag and drop images: resizing possible?

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, resize, markdown, jupyter

I use Jupyter lab on Windows, and use drag and drop to add images to a markdown cell. Very easy, and the image is stored in the .ipynb file, which make distribution of the notebook very easy using just a single file.
Is there a way to resize this image, without loosing this drag-and-drop-workflow?